# Отдельная папка public_admin для админки

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите, как можно сделать, чтобы если пользователь находится в личном кабинете `site.com/admin` то чтобы подключались все стили и скрипты из новой папки `public_admin` а не из `public` ?

**RouteServiceProvider**

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
protected $adminNamespace = 'App\Http\Admin\Controllers';
protected $apiNamespace = 'App\Http\Api\Controllers';

protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->adminNamespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}

public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();
    $this->mapAdminRoutes();
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
}
```

**routes/admin.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Auth::routes();

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    });

});
```

Пытался добавить в файл /.htaccess

```
RewriteRule admin(/.*) public_admin/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

что-то не работает
ещё подключён модуль для админки `adminlte`